# How to find the average of last 52 weeks sales at each time in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file with four columns: date, wholesaler, product, and sales. I am looking for finding average of last 52 weeks sales for each Product and Wholesaler combination at each date. It means what is the average previous sales of product 'A' at wholesaler 'B' at time 'C' in last 52 weeks.

For instance we know sales of product 'A' at wholesaler 'B' at Jan, Apr, May, Aug that are 100, 200, 300, 400 respectively. Let assume we do not have any record before Jan. So the average of previous sale of product 'A' in wholesaler 'B' at Apr is equal to 100/1, and at May is equal to (200+100)/2 and at Aug is (300+200+100)/3.

The following table shows my data:

```
date    wholesaler product  sales
12/31/2012  53929  UPE54     4
12/31/2012  13131  UPE55     1
2/23/2013   13131  UPE55  1156
4/24/2013   13131  UPE55     1
12/1/2013   83389  UPE54     9
12/17/2013  83389  UPE54     1
12/18/2013  52237  UPE54     9
12/19/2013  53929  UME24     1
12/31/2013  82204  UPE55     9
12/31/2013  11209  UME24     4
12/31/2013  52237  UPE54     1
```

Now I am using:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Sample.csv',index_col='date')

expd_gb = df.reset_index().groupby(['wholesaler', 'product'])['sales'].apply(pd.Series.expanding)
idx = df.reset_index().groupby(['wholesaler', 'product', 'date'])['sales'].count().index

cnct = pd.concat([expd_gb.iloc[n].mean().shift(1) for n in range(len(expd_gb))])
cnct.index = idx
```

That gives total average (not last 52 weeks) of previous sales for each Product-Wholesaler combination. The result is:

```
wholesaler  product  date      
11209       UME24    12/31/2013      NaN
13131       UPE55    12/31/2012      NaN
                     2/23/2013       1.0
                     4/24/2013     578.5
52237       UPE54    12/18/2013      NaN
                     12/31/2013      9.0
53929       UME24    12/19/2013      NaN
            UPE54    12/31/2012      NaN
82204       UPE55    12/31/2013      NaN
83389       UPE54    12/1/2013       NaN
                     12/17/2013      9.0
```

As time goes the iteration of sales record is increasing. I need to find out what is the average of sales only for last 52 weeks. It means at a certain date for instance 11/6/2015 what is the average sales of a product at certain wholesaler for last 52 weeks. Thanks a million for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider an `apply` function conditionally averaging the last 52 weeks' sales by wholesaler and product for each record. Without workaround, `groupby()` returns same value for the group whereas you need a type of running group average, so try handling by series. And be sure to convert date to datetime format as you can use the `timedelta()` to count back 52 weeks.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y')

df = pd.read_csv('Sample.csv', index_col='date',
                 parse_dates=[0], date_parser=dateparse)

def last52weeks(x):
    ser = df['sales'][(df.index >= x.name - datetime.timedelta(weeks=52)) &
                      (df.index <= x.name) &
                      (df['wholesaler'] == x[0]) &
                      (df['product'] == x[1])]
    return ser.mean()

df['avg_sales_last52weeks'] = df.apply(last52weeks, axis=1)
df = df.sort_values(['wholesaler', 'product'])

#             wholesaler product  sales    avg_sales_last52weeks
# date                                                          
# 2013-12-31       11209   UME24      4                      4.0
# 2012-12-31       13131   UPE55      1                      1.0
# 2013-02-23       13131   UPE55   1156                    578.5
# 2013-04-24       13131   UPE55      1                    386.0
# 2013-12-18       52237   UPE54      9                      9.0
# 2013-12-31       52237   UPE54      1                      5.0
# 2013-12-19       53929   UME24      1                      1.0
# 2012-12-31       53929   UPE54      4                      4.0
# 2013-12-31       82204   UPE55      9                      9.0
# 2013-12-01       83389   UPE54      9                      9.0
# 2013-12-17       83389   UPE54      1                      5.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's awesome! Do you think `timedelta()` function could work faster? Actually I need to calculate more that 25 million rows and I hope to find fastest way to find the result. Again thanks for your elegant code!

Comment: Wow! Quite a dataset. Consider a database SQL solution using conditional aggregate queries for running avg and index table on date. Then import into pandas df.

Answer (score 1):

If the average is a weekly average, shouldn't you be dividing the sum (per product per wholesaler) by the number of weeks, i.e. 52, rather than getting the mean in cnct = pd.concat([expd_gb.iloc[n].mean().shift(1) for n in range(len(expd_gb))])?

If you have fewer than 52 weeks, then you want to divide the the total sales for that product for that wholesaler by the number of weeks that you have. For instance if in (2016) January you sold 100 widgets, 200 in February and 400 in March, your total sales as of the 1st of April would be 700. There are 31 days in January, 29 in February and 31 in March, so the total number of days is 91, which happens to be 13 weeks (91/7).  The average weekly sales for the that three month period, would thus be 700/13 or approx. 53.85 widgets per week.  It doesn't matter if you had 91 daily records, 13 weekly records or 3 monthly records, the weekly average is still the same.

To get the number of days (and from them weeks) you could have a look at the timedelta objects.  Once you get over 52 weeks, you could also use timedelta to work out what the date was 52 weeks (or 364 days) ago and when you read the file discard anything prior to that date.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! It is a bit complected. In first year since we have less that 52 records per product per wholesaler we can use the mean of all records but for next years we just looking for average of last 52 weeks. Also all product-wholesaler combination do not have weekly records it means for a certain product-wholesaler for instance we have 12 records, so the average should be sum(12 records)/52. Actually I think your comment is true but I do not know how to impediment the logic!